# Select records for one day to 30 days C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, listbox

I want to get records for 1 day to 30 days the Query is working in SQL properly

```
SELECT * FROM Tbl_order WHERE   date >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
```

so what i did in `C#` i use combo box

```
int CmboDays;

for (CmboDays = -1; CmboDays >= -30; CmboDays--)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(CmboDays);
            }  

        private void orderBySearchDays()
        {
            string c = comboBox1.Text;
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(c);

            using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select* from  Tbl_order WHERE date >= DATEADD(day,'"+ x + "', GETDATE()) ; ", connection))
            {                   

                DataTable Tbl_order = new DataTable();
                connection.Open(); //opens the connection
                adapter.Fill(Tbl_order);
                connection.Close(); //Closes the connection

                lst_CustomerNo.DataSource = Tbl_order; //assigns a datasource
                lst_CustomerNo.DisplayMember = "CustomerNo"; //assigns display
                lst_CustomerNo.ValueMember = "CustomerNo";

                lst_OrderName.DataSource = Tbl_order;
                lst_OrderName.DisplayMember = "OrderName";
                lst_OrderName.ValueMember = "OrderName";

                lst_Quantity.DataSource = Tbl_order;
                lst_Quantity.DisplayMember = "Quantity";
                lst_Quantity.ValueMember = "Quantity";

                lst_Price.DataSource = Tbl_order;
                lst_Price.DisplayMember = "Price";
                lst_Price.ValueMember = "Price";

                lst_datetime.DataSource = Tbl_order;
                lst_datetime.DisplayMember = "Date";
                lst_datetime.ValueMember = "Date";

            }
        }
```

so all the data will be display in list box

i'm getting this Error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function.

Am I doing it that Wrong ? 
How to fix the Error ?

Comment: Use parameters.  Don't munge the query string with input values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you chnage x with x.ToString() and remove '

```
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from  Tbl_order WHERE date >= DATEADD(day,"+ x.ToString() + ", GETDATE()) ; ", connection))
```

Comment: Did you remove ' char before and after x too?